# Angular 4 : Get Http Headers from base URL not from an http call

Tags: angular, http-headers

I' am working with a Secure Access Manager, you must enter this tool and click the application name and it will redirect you to your angular application and adding some informations (username) to your base (Http header).

How can I get http headers from my angular application when I visite home page.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done unless you handle the http request within your app. So you could make an http request to index.html on app load to get the headers. So the client calls index.html to load the app. Then the app makes an http request to index.html (or some other resources) to get the headers.

Comment: Ok but you don't think I will be lost in a loop or something like that ?

Comment: It won't be. Since you are requesting index.html with an xhr request you are just getting the contents of the file. Not actually loading it into the DOM. (That would cause index.html to load the app, and cause the infinite loop)

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?